# A network-related or instance-specific error while trying to connect to SQL server 2016 from SSMA tools on Windows 10

Tags: sql-server

I am  trying to connect to SQL server 2016  from SSMA 7.4 tools on Windows 10.

getting below A network-related or instance-specific error.

> Connection to SQL Server failed. A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait
>   operation timed out.)

Kindly let me know if any issue with Firewall or Port or anything need to be configured at Sql server.  Sql services are up and running.

Comment: Did you enable Named Pipes of TCP/IP on the server machine for the SQL Server instance? Are you connecting from a server machine or from remote client machine?

Comment: I have installed sql   server and SSMA tools on same server and I am connecting from same server.Currently Pipes of TCP/IP on the server machine is disabled..

Comment: then it should work using Shared Memory. As the error message says provider is TCP/IP so try enabling TCP/IP.